# package ‘geom_circle’ is not available for this version of R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a radius (in km) around a center point on a Lat/Lon coordinate system and have tried using geom_circle. A couple days ago I was able to plot a circle using

geom_circle(data = Track, aes(x0 = Longitude, y0 = Latitude, r = Radius)) but the circle was much larger than it should be (radius is about 66 km). I'm thinking that's because the units were not the same as the coordinate system.

Anyway, I have gone back to try to get the radius to plot correctly and now I'm getting

Error in geom_circle(data = Track, aes(x0 = Longitude, y0 = Latitude,  :
could not find function "geom_circle"

I tried to install geom_circle and got

> install.packages("geom_circle")
> Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘geom_circle’ is not available for this version of R

I uninstalled ggplot2 then re-installed it and it is active. Everything else is running except for this function.

Is there another function that could plot the radius around a point?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `geom_circle` is a function, not a package. You are probably using the one from the ggforce package. Run `library(ggforce)` to load that package and that function.